# SQL Server 2008 is not supporting special characters

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server-2008

I am facing a silly but a huge problem while inserting special character on SQL Server 2008. I used to have no errors using "addslashes" on MySQL but it is not working on SQL Server 2008. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Every character is special in its own way.

Comment: you should add some code for others to check..

Comment: There is a solution posted in here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1628957/allow-special-characters-sql-server-2008

Comment: nvarchar is not taking some of the special character

Answer (score 0):

Just look at the example in the manual page for [sqlsrv_query()](http://es.php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-query.php):

```
<?php
$sql = "INSERT INTO Table_1 (id, data) VALUES (?, ?)";
$params = array(1, "some data");

$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql, $params);
if( $stmt === false ) {
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
```

The SQLSRV extension is a modern library and provides prepared statements. You don't have to do anything at all to handle special chars.

*Nota: `addslashes()` doesn't work properly on MySQL either.*